# Magento notice message issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I used below code in breadcrumb template to display the notice and messages

```
<div class="GlobalerrorBox">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="message fL">
            <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
        </div>
    <div class="fR"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working for voucher code messages and add to cart messages
but Newsletter error message not displayed in this template.

I need to display newsletter messages in same breadcrumb template

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog article about this:
http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/messages-in-magento-only-loaded-by-default-from-core-session/

The problem is, magento only loads core/session by default:

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

loads only the messages of core/session:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php:79
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->addMessages(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true));
    parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

You need to check, where this message comes from, I would assume `newsletter/session`, but it is: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`

To fix this, you can copy the messages over with an observer:

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
foreach ($customerSession->getMessages()->getItems() as $message) {
    $coreSession->addMessage($message);
}
$customerSession->getMessages(true);
```

Make sure this is done AFTER `$action->loadLayoutUpdates()` / `$this->loadLayoutUpdates()`

More on this in the blogpost.